# Newtonsoft.JSON conditional property source

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft JSON to serialization and deserialization.
I have json representing fields where title property is representing a display Name:

```
{
  "ID": {
    "type": "integer",
    "title": "ID Display Name"
  },
  "TITLE": {
    "type": "string",
    "title": "Title Display name"
  },
  "NAME": {
    "type": "string",
    "title": "Name"
  },
  "CUSTOM_123": {
    "type": "string",
    "title": "CUSTOM_123",
    "formLabel": "CUSTOM_123 Display Name"
  }
  // ... etc
}
```

And I have class:

```
public class Field
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Now everything working fine. But when field name starts with "CUSTOM_" I need to serialize "Title" from property "formLabel".

How could I implement conditional property source?

Comment: What happens if both title and fromLable are supplied?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your JSON to [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), then enumerate all properties, deserialize them one by one to `Field` instance and update a `Title` value if property name in JSON starts with `CUSTOM_` string

```cs
var json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

foreach (var property in json.Properties())
{
    var field = property.Value.ToObject<Field>();
    if (property.Name.StartsWith("CUSTOM_")&&property.Value is JObject propertyObject)
    {
        field.Title = propertyObject["formLabel"]?.Value<string>();
    }
}
```

This approach is simpler, rather than writing a custom converter, I believe

Comment: @Gleb does it answer your question, do you need more details or information?

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize to object using Newtonsoft with custom `JsonConverter`.

Your JSON structure, is a JSON object, that contains multiple child JSON objects (fields). So when deserializing it to .NET you could create a separate class for parent that will have a list of `Fields`. You could also change you JSON to array instead of object and deserialize to `List<Fields>`.

```cs
IList<Field> fields = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Field>>(json, new CustomJsonConverter());
```

```cs
public class CustomJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        IList<Field> fields = new List<Field>();
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        foreach (JToken child in obj.Children())
        {
            Field field = new Field();
            JProperty fieldProp = (JProperty)child;
            JObject fieldValue = (JObject)fieldProp.Value;
            string fieldName = fieldProp.Name;
            if (fieldName .StartsWith("CUSTOM_"))
            {
                field.Title = (string)fieldValue["formLabel"];
                field.Type = (string)fieldValue["type"];
            }
            else
            {
                field.Title = (string)fieldValue["title"];
                field.Type = (string)fieldValue["type"];
            }

            fields.Add(field);
        }

        return fields;
    }


    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Field
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Type{ get; set; }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/5bNihC

Answer (score 0):

having your custom JsonConverter will do the trick,so you will separate the business of deserialization and you can include more business as required in the Convert Method. so in first lines newton soft serializes normally our object to Field then to have the custom business for "Custom_",working fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/aVpB8I

Code as below :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;

namespace testapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"
        {
            ""ID"": {
                ""type"": ""integer"",
                ""title"": ""ID Display Name""
            },
            ""TITLE"": {
                ""type"": ""string"",
                ""title"": ""Title Display name""
            },
            ""NAME"": {
                ""type"": ""string"",
                ""title"": ""Name""
            },
            ""CUSTOM_123"": {
                ""type"": ""string"",
                ""title"": ""CUSTOM_123"",
                ""formLabel"": ""CUSTOM_123 Display Name""
            }
        }";
            List<Field> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Field>>(json, new JobInfoConverter());
        }



        public class Field
        {
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
        }

        public class JobInfoConverter : JsonConverter
        {
            public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                try
                {
                    List<Field> result = new List<Field>();
                    var content = JObject.Load(reader);
                    foreach (var prop in content.Properties())
                    {
                        var parsedValue = prop.Value.ToObject<Field>();
                        if (prop.Name.StartsWith("CUSTOM_"))
                        {
                            parsedValue.title = prop.Value["formLabel"].ToString();
                        }
                        result.Add(parsedValue);

                    }
                    return result;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();

            public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
            {
                return true;
            }

            public override bool CanWrite => true;

        }
    }
```

}